# Choosing Data Type of signature file for parameter in Python Script Tool for Maximum Likelihood Classification?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, spatial-analyst, python-script-tool, parameters

I am working on a script tool for a maximum likelihood classification and I would like to set the signature file as parameter.

What data type do I have to choose in the "Add Script" dialog box in order to set a signature file as parameter?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To work out what Data Type your parameter for the signature file would be, I would consult the [Maximum Likelihood Classification](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/maximum-likelihood-classification.htm) tool documentation where, under [Syntax](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/maximum-likelihood-classification.htm#GUID-C354C29C-0CE7-412C-89B6-8330238C51C0), it says that the Data Type for the `in_signature_file` parameter is File.